# Check if current device has fingerprint or faceId support cordova

Tags: cordova

I am building an app using Cordova with react. I have implement fingerprint and FaceId authentication using this package https://github.com/NiklasMerz/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio.
And I am almost completed but one thing I need to check if the running device has fingerprint or FaceId support so I show the user-related view or errors or text.
As ios have touchId and FaceId(after IPhoneX) and android (fingerprint and facial).
I researched many things and till searching but till now found nothing.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I found the answer in their own documentation.
Hope it might help others.
[image]